# PHP MYSQL/PDO mocking interaction/data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpunit, mockery

Recently getting back up-to-speed with unit testing. Been scouring the net for a good mock PDO SQL class for interactions/data but can't seem to one that doesn't require you to parse what the raw sql is into the mock obj during the test script.

This might be okay for some, but IMO it takes too much away from the test script (I'm trying to minimize complications to help sell the concept to my team at work)

Ideally I'd expect the test to look more like this:

```php
public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{
    // Use PDOMock version in replace of all PDO calls   
    PDOMock::initMockMode();
    // Potentially drive data provider from a file
    $data = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'total' => 1,
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'total' => 1,
        ],
        [
            'id' => 3,
            'total' => 10,
        ],
    ]; 
    PDOMock::setTableData('db.example_table', $data);
}

public function testSqlMock()
{
    // Presumming the sumTableValues() method runs a simple sum query over the db.example_table using the regular \PDO class
    $total = TestClass::sumTableValues();

    $this->assertEquals(12, $total); // assertion passes due to PDOMock class using set data over live mysql data
}
```

It doesn't really need to have the fancy `PDOMock::initMockMode()` logic either as I can compromise by adding a `setMockMode()` in my sqlclass to just use the mocked version instead of `\PDO`

Hope this makes sense; any ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated!